# Is There a Way to Automate the Creation of Data Studio Reports with Different Data Sources

Tags: looker-studio

So I am working on client reporting for my agency and Data Studio seems to check all the boxes we need.

However, we have several clients and I need a way to automate the creation of Data Studio reports.

The general steps I would want the script to follow are:

1. Copy a template report that I've already created
2. Establish data source based on a list of analytics property IDs etc
3. Add specific emails to share with client and internal parties

So data studio has an api that I've looked in to but it seems primarily built around building connectors.

I have considered using puppeteer or something of that nature but would much rather use an API if available.

I have yet to really dig in to coding side of it, I am more having trouble finding out if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Data Studio for some months and I face the same problem. Since we don't have many clients yet is not a big problem, but **I didn't found any official way to automate the creation of reports** (Apps Script functions only for creating connectors).

Sorry it is not a positive answer but it seems we have to wait, they´re still improving it (back when I started some months ago, we didn't have auto-refresh for data).